# The argument type 'Dialog' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'

Tags: flutter, dialog, widget, variable-assignment

I am trying to display a `Form` Widget 2ithin a `Dialog` as following:

```
onPressed: () async {
  switch (currentScreen.toString()) {
    case 'OverviewScreen':
      () => showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: const Dialog(child: FormBasicDetails()));
      break;
  }
},
```

But I get the following error at the `builder` line:

> The argument type 'Dialog' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`builder` provides callback method with context.

It will be

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => const Dialog(
```